# What is the meaning of npm view dependencies output?

Tags: node.js, npm

When executing `npm view karma@0.12.36 dependencies` the dependencies are not displayed uniformly.

What does it mean if a dependency is marked with a single quote and green font?

What does it mean if a dependency is in a white font?

[image: Npm Output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing the output of [`util.format()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_format_format), which is trying to create a valid Javascript literal.

Since `-`s are not valid in identifiers, they must be quoted.

Comment: That's embarrasing. In my defense, JSON vs Javascript Object literals was causing a haze :). Plus I didn't know you could use illegal names like that. I learned something.